# How to "get" an attribute of a QLabel widget

Tags: python, pyqt

I understand that QLabel attributes such as frameGeometry, pixmap and text can be recovered using their respective commands. But is it possible to get the value of "frame shadow" around each of these label widgets?

I have 3 Labels placed inside a Frame (inside a Window) using qt-designer. I assigned shadows for each of these labels by calling `self.label_1.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)` or `self.label_1.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Plain)` within the QMainWindow class.
Now I wish to update their shadow attributes after checking to see if one of them is Raised or Plain. The error says that: 'QLabel' object has no attribute 'FrameShadow'. But why so if I was able to set it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QLabel` inherits from `QFrame` and therefore has an accessor [`frameShadow()`](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/api/qtwidgets/qframe.html#frameShadow) for that property.

Unlike in other frameworks, Qt accessors don't start with `get`...

Comment: capital letter was the problem. frameShadow() returns value 16 for plain and 48 for raised.